# How to Conditionally Add an object in an array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am getting a type error in  `<RenderFormFields formFields={formFieldsData} />` that:-

`Types of property 'type' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"select"'.ts(2322) RenderFormFields.tsx(17, 3): The expected type comes from property 'formFields' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RenderFormFieldsProps'`

Interestingly, when I remove the conditional insertion part from the array, this type error vanishes !

```js
import RenderFormFields from '@common/RenderFormFields';
import {
  BlockSeparator, PrimaryButton,
  PrimaryInput, PrimarySelect,
} from '@paf-ui-components-library';
import { IProps } from '@paf-ui-components-library/PrimaryInput';
import React from 'react';

import AnnualRevenueField from './AnnualRevenueField';
import BranchLocationsField from './BranchLocationsField';
import CurrentBankStatementsField from './CurrentBankStatementsField';
import useBusinessInformationForm from './hooks/useBusinessForm';
import MajorCustomersField from './MajorCustomersField';
import MajorSuppliersField from './MajorSuppliersField';
import PrimaryBankField from './PrimaryBankField';
import TradeAreasField from './TradeAreasField';

export const RefactoredBusinessInformationForm: React.FC = () => {
  const {
    annualRevenueTypeOptions,
    appendBranchLocations,
    appendMajorCustomers,
    appendMajorSuppliers,
    appendPrimaryTradeAreas,
    branchLocationFields,
    businessIndustryOptions,
    handleContinue,
    handleSubmit,
    industryType,
    loading,
    majorCustomersFields,
    majorSuppliersFields,
    naicsCodeOptions,
    primaryTradeAreaFields,
    removeBranchLocations,
    removeMajorCustomers,
    removeMajorSuppliers,
    removePrimaryTradeAreas,
    watch,
  } = useBusinessInformationForm();

  const formFieldsData = [
    {
      data: businessIndustryOptions,
      name: 'businessInformation.industryType',
      title: 'Business Industry',
      type: 'select',
    },
// when I remove this conditional insertion, the type error vanishes !
    ...(industryType === 'Other' ? [{ 
      name: 'businessInformation.otherIndustryType',
      title: 'Other Business Industry Type',
      type: 'text',
    }] : [{}]),
    {
      data: naicsCodeOptions,
      name: 'businessInformation.naicsCode',
      title: 'NAICS Code',
      type: 'select',
    },
    {
      info: 'Describe the business revenue generating activity',
      name: 'businessInformation.natureOfBusiness',
      title: 'Nature of Business',
      type: 'textarea',
    },
    {
      info: 'Provide a description of your products and/or services',
      name: 'businessInformation.businessProductsAndServices',
      title: 'Business Products and Services',
      type: 'textarea',
    },
    {
      name: 'businessInformation.numberOfBranches',
      title: 'Number of Branches',
      type: 'number',
      allowedDecimalPlaces: 0,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <BlockSeparator
        heading="Business Information"
      >

        <RenderFormFields formFields={formFieldsData} />
        <h1>bruh</h1>

        <PrimarySelect
          data={businessIndustryOptions}
          name="businessInformation.industryType"
          title="Business Industry"
        />
        {industryType === 'Other' && (
          <PrimaryInput
            name="businessInformation.otherIndustryType"
            title="Other Business Industry Type"
            type="text"
          />
        )}
        <PrimarySelect
          data={naicsCodeOptions}
          name="businessInformation.naicsCode"
          title="NAICS Code"
        />

        <PrimaryInput
          info="Describe the business revenue generating activity"
          name="businessInformation.natureOfBusiness"
          title="Nature of Business"
          type="textarea"
        />

        <PrimaryInput
          info="Provide a description of your products and/or services"
          name="businessInformation.businessProductsAndServices"
          title="Business Products and Services"
          type="textarea"
        />

        <PrimaryInput
          allowedDecimalPlaces={0}
          name="businessInformation.numberOfBranches"
          title="Number of Branches"
          type="number"
        />

        <BranchLocationsField
          branchLocationFields={branchLocationFields}
          onAdd={appendBranchLocations}
          onRemove={removeBranchLocations}
        />

        <PrimaryInput
          name="businessInformation.noOfEmployees"
          title="Number of Employees"
          type="number"
        />

        <TradeAreasField
          onAdd={appendPrimaryTradeAreas}
          onRemove={removePrimaryTradeAreas}
          primaryTradeAreaFields={primaryTradeAreaFields}
        />

        <MajorCustomersField
          majorCustomersFields={majorCustomersFields}
          onAdd={appendMajorCustomers}
          onRemove={removeMajorCustomers}
        />

        <MajorSuppliersField
          majorSuppliersFields={majorSuppliersFields}
          onAdd={appendMajorSuppliers}
          onRemove={removeMajorSuppliers}
        />

        <PrimaryBankField />

        <CurrentBankStatementsField
          existingDocumentUrl={watch('businessInformation.currentBankStatementsDoc.frontSideUrl')}
        />

        <AnnualRevenueField
          annualRevenueTypeOptions={annualRevenueTypeOptions}
        />
      </BlockSeparator>

      <BlockSeparator>
        <PrimaryButton
          loading={loading}
          onClick={handleSubmit(({ businessInformation }) => (
            handleContinue(businessInformation)
          ))}
          variantsStyle={['primary-button-submit-accent']}
        >
          Continue
        </PrimaryButton>
      </BlockSeparator>
    </>
  );
};
```

RenderFormFields.tsx

```js
import {
  PrimaryInput, PrimarySelect,
} from '@paf-ui-components-library';
import { IProps as PrimaryInputProps } from '@paf-ui-components-library/PrimaryInput';
import { IProps as PrimarySelectProps } from '@paf-ui-components-library/PrimarySelect';
import React from 'react';

export interface PrimaryInputField extends PrimaryInputProps {
  type: 'text' | 'number' | 'textarea';
}
interface PrimarySelectField extends PrimarySelectProps {
  type: 'select';
}
type FormField = PrimaryInputField | PrimarySelectField;

interface RenderFormFieldsProps {
  formFields: FormField[];
}

const RenderFormFields: React.FC<RenderFormFieldsProps> = ({ formFields }) => (
  <>
    {formFields.map((field) => (
      <React.Fragment key={field.name}>
        {field.type === 'select' && (
          <PrimarySelect data={field.data} name={field.name} title={field.title} />
        )}
        {field.type === 'text' && (
          <PrimaryInput name={field.name} title={field.title} type="text" />
        )}
        {field.type === 'textarea' && (
          <PrimaryInput info={field.info} name={field.name} title={field.title} type="textarea" />
        )}
        {field.type === 'number' && (
          <PrimaryInput
            allowedDecimalPlaces={(field as PrimaryInputField).allowedDecimalPlaces}
            name={field.name}
            title={field.title}
            type="number"
          />
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}
  </>
);

export default RenderFormFields;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using the `as` keyword.

In TypeScript, the `as` keyword is used to explicitly type cast a value to a different type.

```js
  const formFieldsData: FormField[] = [
    {
      data: businessIndustryOptions,
      name: 'businessInformation.industryType',
      title: 'Business Industry',
      type: 'select',
    },
    ...(industryType
      ? [
        {
          name: 'businessInformation.otherIndustryType',
          title: 'Other Business Industry Type',
          type: 'text',
        } as FormField,
      ]
      : []),
    {
      data: naicsCodeOptions,
      name: 'businessInformation.naicsCode',
      title: 'NAICS Code',
      type: 'select',
    },
    {
      info: 'Describe the business revenue generating activity',
      name: 'businessInformation.natureOfBusiness',
      title: 'Nature of Business',
      type: 'textarea',
    },
    {
      info: 'Provide a description of your products and/or services',
      name: 'businessInformation.businessProductsAndServices',
      title: 'Business Products and Services',
      type: 'textarea',
    },
    {
      name: 'businessInformation.numberOfBranches',
      title: 'Number of Branches',
      type: 'number',
      allowedDecimalPlaces: 0,
    },
  ];
```